# Is there a TODO list app for mac you can change Font Size?

Tags: mac, applications, reminders

You can't do it, in wunderlist, reminders, any.do, etc.

You really need to ruin your eyes to read you notes.

Answer (score 3):

With [OmniFocus](http://www.omnigroup.com/omnifocus/) you can change the font and display styles with a ton of options.

[image]

Comment: Thanks this is an option. I'm looking for something more simple like indeed Reminders... very simple and clean interface

Answer (score -1):

Google Keep might have a default text size that is large enough.